# Flutter: shared preference MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter

I use shared preference with Flutter,

I always get error:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
> getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences_android)

1. I did flutter clean
2. I did flutter upgrade
3. I did fresh install

nothing help, I googled it, no found any soultion for that

in fact, there is one soultion and it partially works, when I have used in main():

> SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});

partially works it means, after re-open the app, all values initialized to null.

so **SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({})** not a good soultion

any suggestions?

P.S: flutter doctor output:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.7.0-27.0.pre.25, on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
> 5.15.0-58-generic, locale en_IL)
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
>
> [✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop [✓] Android
> Studio (version 2022.1)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2) [✓] Connected
> device (3 available)
>
> [✓] HTTP Host Availability
>
> • No issues found!

Comment: have you tried switching flutter channel to stable?

Comment: Upgraded to stable version (Channel stable, 3.0.0), still same issue

Comment: try running
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade

Comment: current stable sdk version for flutter is 3.7.0

Comment: as you can see, I am on 3.7, thanks a lot

Comment: are you use the correct plugin?
because there are `sharedpreference` and `shared_preferences`. ?

Comment: I use: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/key-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soulution that did work for me:

update MainActivity.kt

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine) // add this line
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the accepted answer but it didn't work for me. I was trying to access shared preference in Firebase messaging background handler. After spending hours on this issue I found this solution:

Install these two dependencies with default shared_preferences dependency.

1. https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences_android
2. https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences_ios

Then before accessing shared preference use the below code and it will work.

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) SharedPreferencesAndroid.registerWith();
if (Platform.isIOS) SharedPreferencesIOS.registerWith();
```